# SQL checando conteúdo do dado

Tags: php, sql

Estou fazendo um sistema de pesquisa para meu blog (ele já procura categoria do post e tags). Existe algum comando do SQL (ou se o SQL próprio já faz isso) que faça ele checar todo o conteúdo do dado encontrado na tabela e me retorne?

Ex: eu coloco uma tag "teste" para meu post e procuro por "teste" ele vai me retornar o post certo (porque são N tags para 1 post). Agora, se eu coloco no conteúdo do post (ou no título) "estou fazendo um teste", ele vai procurar o "teste" lá meio das outras palavras?

Tem algum jeito de fazer isso ou vou ter fazer um explode nos resultados da pesquisa pra pesquisar palavra por palavra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para realizar uma consulta pelo conteúdo basta utilizar o coringa "%". Para entender melhor vamos ao exemplo:

1. Caso você queira pesquisar um registro (ex. a palavra esporte) que exista no início de alguma palavra dentro do texto:

   "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE conteudo LIKE '%esporte'"
2. Se você quer pesquisar algo que termine com a palavra pesquisada:

   "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE conteudo LIKE 'esporte%'"
3. E por último, caso queira pesquisar algo que comece e ou termine com a palavra pesquisada

   "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE conteudo LIKE '%esportes%'"

Para mais informações consulte o link http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Comment: Nossa, exatamente o que eu precisava. Muito obrigado mesmo ;)